# Rails Json POST create's value for attributes set to null even though server registers the value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, crud

I have an iOS project that sends a *Person* class with one attribute *name* which is "data" to the server. The server sees it, but sets it to *null*.

```
Processing PeopleController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-13 03:55:46) [POST]
  Parameters: {"name"=>"data"}

Person Create (0.4ms)   INSERT INTO "people" ("created_at", "updated_at", "name")
VALUES('2012-01-13 11:55:46', '2012-01-13 11:55:46', NULL)
Completed in 27ms (View: 1, DB: 0) | 200 OK
```

It's a scaffold generated Rails app with *Person has_many dogs* and *dogs belongs_to person*.
The following is the scaffold generated create method:

```
def create
  @person = Person.new(params[:person])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Person was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@person) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @person }
      format.json { render :json => @person }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @person.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render :json => @person.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to write a custom JSON parser?
I use Rails version 2.3.4 with Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: first of all, you need to show us your code

Comment: please post the content of the `create` method in controller!

Comment: @davidb hey hi dave, i kinda knew i was supose to add the content but i didnt know how, im  more familar with xcode than ruby. I dont know much at all bout ruby can you ponit me in the right direction? how would i set the person's class's name to the data sent in from json?  eg. format person.name = json.name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are building your model using `params[:person]`. Or, you can see that the parameters received are `{"name"=>"data"}`, when they should be `{"person" => {"name"=>"data"}}`

Comment: Hey thnx alot i didnt even notice that! Now i have to fix my xcode to output the right json